# TypeORM - findAll method to find all articles of an user

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I want find all articles of one user from **TypeORM** package.

On **Sequelize**, I have this:

```
async findAllByUser(userUuid: string, findOptions: object): Promise<Article[]> {
    return await Article.findAll<Article>({
        include: [{
            model: User,
            where: {
                uuid: userUuid
            }
        }]
    });
}
```

I'd like an alternative for **TypeORM**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can join if the relationship was defined in model

```js
export class Article {
    /// ... other columns

    @ManyToOne(type => Author, author => author.articles)
    author: Author;
}
```

There are two way to query: `find*` method or `QueryBuilder`

```js
// find*

createConnection(/*...*/).then(async connection => {

    /*...*/
    let articleRepository = connection.getRepository(Article);
    let articles = await articleRepository.find({ relations: ["author"] });

}).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

```js
// Query Builder
const articles = await connection
    .getRepository(Article)
    .createQueryBuilder("article") 
    .leftJoinAndSelect("article.author", "user")
    .getMany();
```

You can read the [documentation](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm) for more detail